# Python Pagination Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, pagination, beautifulsoup

I'm doing some simple web scraping, and need to find a better way to loop through pagination on the target site. The only way I could do this was to write 10 + "for loops" to get it to work. 
Basically I'm looking for a "Next" icon in the url, if it exist, I need to grab the parent link of the icon image and append it to the url, go to the new updated url, and search for the same icon and repeat until I get to the last page (the icon will be gone). 
How could I perform this without hard coding a bunch of for loops?

```
        url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/"
        r = requests.get(wurl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

        for img in soup.findAll("img"):
            if "/Next_Icon" in img["src"]:
                link = img.find_parent("a", href=True)
                extLink = (link["href"])
                url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/" + extLink
```

Comment: Use recursion or a stack/queue, there are plenty of examples of both on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url_stack = ["http://www.somewebsite.com/"]

while url_stack:
    wurl = url_stack.pop()
    r = requests.get(wurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    for img in soup.findAll("img"):
        if "/Next_Icon" in img["src"]:
            link = img.find_parent("a", href=True)
            extLink = (link["href"])
            url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/" + extLink
            url_stack.append(url)
```

You should use list to store all the urls

Comment: Ha-Ha that is funny. You write "wurl" like I do. Yes, actually I'll be using JSON to store everything in. But I just needed to get over this hump, so I've been printing it. 
Thank you so much, this looks really good! It will work.